# I lost my home folder on update to 16.04, is it possible to retrieve it?

Tags: command-line, unity, nvidia, permissions, login

I have only one user on my computer, me - `paul`. My update to 16.04 crashed at the very last second, when I tried to restart I was experiencing login loop. After some research, I found that there was likely a problem with my Nvidia drivers - so I found some terminal code to remove the drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '$2~/nvidia/ {print $2}')
```

this let me log back into my computer, but there was no Unity. So I tried to re-install it myself using the instructions from [here](http://itsfoss.com/install-unity-8-desktop-ubuntu/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20ItsFoss%20%28Its%20FOSS%21%20An%20Open%20Source%20Blog%29)

Now I am back to login loop and when I Ctrl+f1 to get to the terminal to log in I see that there is no Home folder:

```
no directory logging in with home=/
```

when I `cd` home and `ls` I see nothing.

I created a new user with `adduser paul1` - and I can log into that account. From there, I searched my computer for my `paul` home directory:

- and it appears to have moved into my `media` directory
- but I cannot access it, even if I use the terminal to navigate to it as `sudo` or `paul`
- I can see `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Pictures`, etc., but they appear to be either empty, or inaccessible.

I am not positive that this is really my home folder, and it just moved - or if it is something else. I am afraid to move it, or create a new `paul` folder in Home - I don't want to lose all the files that I had in my Home directory.

Does anybody have any advice?